# What are opportunistic locks and how are they different from pessimistic locks?

Tags: mongodb, locking, optimistic-locking, pessimistic-locking

I was recently going through mongodb a complete guide and found the following statement - "uses **opportunistic locking** in its WiredTiger storage engine". On searching about opportunistic locking on the internet I found this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/opportunistic-locks) it explains it to be fairly similar to pessimistic locking. Is there any difference between the two and if there is what is it?

Comment: Can you share the link where you read the statement  *uses opportunistic locking in its WiredTiger storage engine*? It is rather confusing that you mentioned opportunistic locking despsite the 2 facts of wiredTiger should be using optimistic lock in general and you are tagging optimisitic-locking for the question.

Comment: You will find the this statement in the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=vq_CDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT11&lpg=PT11&dq=mongodb+%22opportunistic%22+locking&source=bl&ots=nSgW2Tu936&sig=ACfU3U3vbDS1CGhxn3GDW5u17OB5GkXDog&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi36e-oh-DzAhVdzDgGHeOXB6oQ6AF6BAgpEAM#v=onepage&q=mongodb%20opportunistic%20locking&f=false)